# Trouble migrating from twitter search api to status api

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter, local-storage

I was using search api to fetch tweets of a particular user. It worked perfectly except that it couldn't fetch tweets where username contained numbers.

So upon suggestion I replaced the query with that of status api. But am unable to parse it now!!

Posting below the old code to display the tweet details.

```
function displayTweets(data) {
        //var data = JSON.parse(d);
        $("#heading").html("Tweets: <span class='handleName'>@"+handle+"</span>");
    $("#loading").remove();
    $("#tweets").children().remove();
    alert("1");
    $.each(data.results, function(i, tweet) {
        alert("hi");
        if(tweet.text !== undefined) {
         // Calculate how many hours ago was the tweet posted
            var date_tweet = new Date(tweet.created_at);
            var date_now   = new Date();
            var date_diff  = date_now - date_tweet;
            var hours      = Math.round(date_diff/(1000*60*60));        // calc time to tweet in hours
            if(hours < 1){
                hours = Math.round(date_diff/(1000*60));
                if(hours<1){
                    $("#tweets").append($("<li/>").html(tweet.text+" <span class='tweetTime'>--a moment ago.</span>"));
                }else{
                    $("#tweets").append($("<li/>").html(tweet.text+" <span class='tweetTime'>--"+hours+" minute(s) ago.</span>"));
                }
            }else{
                $("#tweets").append($("<li/>").html(tweet.text+" <span class='tweetTime'>--"+hours+" hour(s) ago.</span>"));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now the query string i am using to get the response and store the response in localstorage:

```
function sendRequest(handle, noOfTweets, boolDisplay){
    $.getJSON("http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name="+ handle + "&count=" + noOfTweets + "&callback=?", function(data) {
    if(boolDisplay){
        displayTweets(data);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("tweets"+handle, JSON.stringify(data));
  });
```

Please tell me what changes are needed!!
    }

Comment: I have also tried changing  displayTweets(data); to  displayTweets(JSON.parse(data)); yet its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structures of the returned JSON is completely different.  See the examples at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search and https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

For example, you're saying

```
$.each(data.results, function(i, tweet) {
```

But the user timeline doesn't contain a results element.

You want something like

```
$.each(data, (function(i, tweet) {
```

Comment: Thanks!
Can you just tell me whether trim_user=true will help me in my case?

Also any 'short' way to provide link to that tweet or add a retweet option?